# GalleryAllShapesAndTextboxes not displaying properly

Tags: vba, powerpoint, ribbonx

I'm quite a noobie so bear with me.

I'm trying to set up this gallery control con my ribbon to replicate the behavior it has on the Home Tab, Drawing Section.  It shows a summary of shapes and then you can expand to see all the options.  I'm just getting the latter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [gallery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#gallery) control doesn't provide all features to developers. All possible customizations you can find describes in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)